# Progress bar percentage is increasing and decreasing, never finishing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, geoprocessing, clip

I am trying to clip a raster by shapefile perimeter using the Clip tool. The percentage has been jumping between 0% and 100% for over an hour, back and forth, climbing to 100% then dropping down to 35% or so all over again. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm desperately trying to cut down this raster file so I can continue doing my work, since it has to re-draw the entire raster every time I add a point to a point shapefile.

I'm using ArcGIS10 with SP4 installed. This occurred in ArcMap while running the Clip tool under Data Management Tools > Raster > Raster Processing > Clip.

Comment: Rachel, please take some time to read through the faq and then reformulate your question. It's nearly impossible to answer your question without even knowing what program/version you're using.

Comment: Sorry about that. They did end up working, but the error occured the entire time and I had no sense of how close it was to done. I'm using ArcGIS10 with SP4 installed. This occurred in ArcMap while running the Clip tool under Data Management Tools > Raster > Raster Processing > Clip.

Comment: An easier workaround may be to calculate pyramids.  Then ArcGIS will be able to quickly render the image at a variety of scales.  You can do this in the catalog: right-click raster > Build Pyramids...

Answer (score 1):

The progress bar only appears to be jumping up and down. What is actually happening is that the geoprocessing tool has an individual percentage/progress bar for each of its subset calculations. A subset calculation will complete at 100% and then a new calculation will begin at 0%.

ArcGIS does not always inform you that this is happening, and when it happens with a lot of subset calculations in a short time period, it does appear to be jumping back and forth.

One window that you can pull up that *might* bring more insight into the calculation is the *Geoprocessing Results* window. You can access this window during the calcuation by clicking **Geoprocessing** on the drop down window then selecting **Results**:

[image: Geoprocessing Results window]